# jquery datepicker and jquery mask not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, maskedinput

I have this piece of code that uses [jquery datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) and [jquery masked input](https://github.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput).

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(document).on('click', '#date', function () { 
        var me = $("#date");   
        me.datepicker({
            showOn: 'focus',
            altFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
            dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
            minDate: '12/12/2000',
            maxDate: '12/12/2020'
        }).focus();
        me.mask('99/99/9999');
    }).on('select', '#date', function () {
        var me = $("#date");
        me.mask('99/99/9999');
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Z2Ws/)

The code uses [jquery on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) because the input element in the application is dynamically added into the page. And the masked input is also registered from `select` event because user can come to the input by pressing tab from previous input.

It doesn't work on `Firefox 31`, but it works fine on `Chrome 36` and `IE 11`.
When the input field is empty, user should be able to type anything (based on masked filter) in the input element.

Kindly suggest me what's wrong with the code.

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/6Z2Ws/2/

Comment: @AamirAfridi, I appreciated the help, but the mask is also required when the input is activated from another input (e.g. pressing tab from previous input), anyway I already solve it, thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just fixed it by changing the `select` into `focus`, I can't remember why I used `select` in the first place.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(document).on('click', '#date', function () { 
        var me = $("#date");   
        me.datepicker({
            showOn: 'focus',
            altFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
            dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
            minDate: '12/12/2000',
            maxDate: '12/12/2020'
        }).focus();
    }).on('focus', '#date', function () {
        var me = $("#date");
        me.mask('99/99/9999');
    });
});
```

[Fixed JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dg459/)

Comment: Why don't you just use a single `focus` event ? http://jsfiddle.net/uLZ6y/ (Note : you missed and `=` sign after all your `type` input attributes)

Comment: @Brewal, Thanks. The requirement requires that the datepicker appears when it's clicked